# Ranking values in pandas based off a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking

I am fairly new to python. I have a dataframe that looks something along these lines:

```
Points   Year_Month 
5000     March-2021
4000     March-2021
3500     March-2021
4500     February-2021
2000     February-2021
1500     February-2021
6000     January-2021
1200     January-2021
1000     January-2021
```

I want to create a new column that ranks the 'Points' column based on the 'Year_Month' column.
So the output that I want would look something like the following:

```
Points   Year_Month     Rank  
5000     March-2021     1
4000     March-2021     2
3500     March-2021     3
4500     February-2021  1
2000     February-2021  2
1500     February-2021  3
6000     January-2021   1
1200     January-2021   2
1000     January-2021   3
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try showing some code that you've already written to help us improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby` and `rank`

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['Year_Month'])['Points'].rank(method='first', ascending=False)
```

Look at what sort of rank method is suitable by looking at the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html).